# Alignment of <input type="submit"> in Chrome changes if value=""

Tags: css, forms, google-chrome, alignment

I have a simple HTML form with only two elements -- a text box and a submit button -- that need to be horizontally aligned.

The button has a background image, and I would like to set its value="".

In Safari and Firefox, the alignment is maintained if I set the line-height on the elements.

In Chrome, however, this is not enough.  I have to set the value=" " (note the space), or give it another text value.  Otherwise, the elements shift.

This is the HTML and css

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="email" class="textBox" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitSubscribe" class="submitButton" value="" />
</form>

.submitButton{
    width:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    background:url('');
}

.textBox{
    line-height:30px;
}

#email{
    width:146px;
}
```

Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EmCQJ/5/

Does anybody know why Chrome calculates the alignment differently with the text in the value attribute than when the value is blank?  Leaving that space in the value feels like a hack solution to me, but I've tried all the obvious css fixes and still can't get it working.  Any input is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Setting `font-size` for button maybe help...

Comment: It seems to me you should be using <input type="image">

Comment: Your `submit` button will be fine, if you **explicitly** define the `height` of it, to pass all browser compatibility.

Comment: @NOX That was my first thought, but it does not appear to have solved the problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/katiev/EmCQJ/13/

Comment: @Tom You are right.  I've made the change in my own code for semantic correctness.  But the same formatting issue still applies.

Comment: What if you just get rid of the value attribute?

Comment: @Tom: Still doesn't change the alignment.

Comment: @NOX: I tried the font-size, as well, but no change.  It seems like this should be really simple and obvious.

Comment: @user480029 I removed the value attribute and it lined up fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EmCQJ/33/ Granted the "Submit" text shows up now but that has to do with it not being set to type="image" . . . If you're still having issues, can you please provide an updated jsfiddle that has type="image" set and with real images so I don't waste time hoping things work right with empty image attributes?

Comment: @TOM  I've updated the jsfiddle, this time with the input type set to image.  Interestingly, the problem exists now across all browsers.  I suspect that when you removed the value attribute, the default "submit" text did the same thing that the blank space text did in my hack.  Just would like to find out what that is.  Thanks again! http://jsfiddle.net/EmCQJ/36/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/EmCQJ/38/

The key here was

```
vertical-align: text-top;
```

It seems the input-text and input-image elements have different baselines (the default setting for vertical-align) but the same text-top line.

You should manually set the margin, padding, and border of the input-text element because different browsers have different defaults. When doing this, remember height is the size of the element less the margin, padding, and border so if you want a total height of 30px make sure to subtract 1px from the top and 1px from the bottom giving you a CSS height of 28px.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and super detailed explanation!